# Absolute position and pagebreak

Tags: spacing, textpos

I need to generate random text and if random text = `\textheight`, break page automatically and start new page with the rest of the text in the same `textblock` environment. I read many articles, but the biggest problem is with absolute position, which ignores everything except `\null\newpage`. Help me, please!

I have code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}

%define used packages
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[left=2cm, top=1.5cm, right=1cm, bottom=2cm, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic}  

%specify layout settings
\voffset = 0pt
\hoffset = 0pt
\headheight = 45pt
\headsep = 0.5cm
\footskip = 0.5cm
\oddsidemargin = -14pt 
\pagecolor{white}
\setlength\columnsep{38pt}

%define custom colors  
\definecolor{MySpecColor}{RGB}{245,247,246}
\definecolor{MySpecTitleColor}{RGB}{249,206,143}
\definecolor{MySpecHeaderColor}{RGB}{221,130,0}

%create new commands
\newcommand{\parallelcolor}{ %
    \color{black}\small\onehalfspacing
        }
\newcommand{\changecolor}{%
    \color{MySpecTitleColor} 
}
\newcommand{\redefinecolor}{%
    \color{black} 
}
\newcommand{\redefineweight}{%
    \bf
}
\newcommand{\setownstyle}{
%   \rmfamily
    \LARGE\color{black}
}
\newcommand{\setownspecstyle}{
%\rmfamily
\LARGE\color{MySpecHeaderColor}
}

%define renewcommands
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}


\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \AtTextLowerLeft{\color{MySpecColor}%
 \rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}}}

%define mainpart of document
\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{12}(2.2,2.5)
\setownstyle Text\\[0pt]
\setownstyle Text\\[0pt]
\setownspecstyle Text
\begin{spacing}{1.3}
\begin{multicols}{2}{
\parallelcolor Text
\vfill
\columnbreak
\parallelcolor Text
}
\end{multicols}
\begin{spacing}{0.7}
\begin{multicols}{2}{
\parallelcolor Text
\vfill
\columnbreak
\parallelcolor Text
}
\end{multicols}
\end{spacing}
\end{spacing}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx, I edited your question using the `{}` button so the code section formats correctly (just indenting by four spaces is equivalent) could you please edit the question to add lines at the top showing which document class or further packages you use. I tried article class but  got `! Undefined control sequence. l.5 \setownstyle`

Comment: Thanks for editing the question, but it still doesn't work for me (TeXlive 2012) If you do not get an error about `\setownstyle` could you check which file does define it and I will attempt to update that package.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use `\textblock`?

Comment: I used \textblock, because my text should be overlay the colored rectangle, which should present in every page. I find \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}, which solved this problem. Is there another way to do the same?

Comment: @Sveta Sorry, but it's not very clear: there is *no* colored rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am not understanding the question and this is too long for a comment, so I'll leave it temporarily as an answer.

Things seem to work as expected removing the textblock environment, as in the following example (in my example code I deleted some of the packages and settings that were not relevant):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[left=2cm, top=1.5cm, right=1cm, bottom=2cm, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\setlength\columnsep{38pt}

%define custom colors  
\definecolor{MySpecColor}{RGB}{245,247,246}
\definecolor{MySpecTitleColor}{RGB}{249,206,143}
\definecolor{MySpecHeaderColor}{RGB}{221,130,0}

%create new commands
\newcommand{\parallelcolor}{ %
    \color{black}\small\onehalfspacing
        }
\newcommand{\changecolor}{%
    \color{MySpecTitleColor} 
}
\newcommand{\redefinecolor}{%
    \color{black} 
}
\newcommand{\redefineweight}{%
    \bf
}
\newcommand{\setownstyle}{
%   \rmfamily
    \LARGE\color{black}
}
\newcommand{\setownspecstyle}{
%\rmfamily
\LARGE\color{MySpecHeaderColor}
}

%define renewcommands
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \AtTextLowerLeft{\color{MySpecColor}%
 \rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}}}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \AtTextLowerLeft{\color{MySpecColor}%
 \rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}}} 

%define mainpart of document
\begin{document}

\setownstyle Text\\
\setownstyle Text\\
\setownspecstyle Text
\begin{spacing}{1.3}
\begin{multicols}{2}{
\parallelcolor Text
\vfill
\columnbreak
\parallelcolor Text
}
\end{multicols}
\begin{spacing}{0.7}
\begin{multicols}{2}{
\parallelcolor Text
\vfill
\columnbreak
\parallelcolor Text
}
\end{multicols}
\end{spacing}
\end{spacing}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried to remove \textblock environment. But I found next troubles with margins. I need to have top, left, right, botton text margins. Now My generated text has not got them in relation to \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \AtTextLowerLeft{\color{MySpecColor}%  Add left and right margins I solved with \begin{addmargin}[0.7cm]{0.7cm} of \usepackage{scrextend}. But How to work around with top and button margins?